# Retrieve Path of admin.php

Tags: wp-admin, paths

Is there a better way of retrieving the path of admin.php and the url of wp-admin.css?

What I can think of is:

```
$adminphppath = ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\admin.php';
$admincssurl = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.css";
```

But, some may be changing the admin path for security. So I need a more reliable way.

[Edit] I need the system path for admin.php, not url. Because I need to include it.

Comment: You cannot change the wp-admin folder name. You can rewrite it url wise but it ain't going to make anything more secure.

Comment: So is ABSPATH the most reliable way?

Comment: yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) function for wp-admin.css file and ABSPATH for admin.php.

```
$admin_php_path = ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/admin.php';
$admin_css_url = admin_url( 'css/wp-admin.css' );
```

Comment: For the css file it works thanks but for admin.php,  actually I need to use include() so I need the system path, not the url. If I include with url, I get `Warning: require() [function.require]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0`

Comment: O, sorry about that. `admin_url()` will return URL which is useless with require or include, so as @Wyck said you should use `ABSPATH`. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, but this accounts for installs where wp-admin is not the admin directory

```
$admin_abspath = str_replace( site_url(), ABSPATH, admin_url() );
$admin_php_path = $admin_abspath . '/wp-admin/admin.php';
```

Comment: Close, but results in duplicate slashes right at `wp-admin`.... (as in `/my/path/to//wp-admin`)